# Nonabelian $H^2$ and Galois descent

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, reference-request, algebraic-groups, arithmetic-geometry, galois-cohomology

I would like to know whether the following metatheorem on nonabelian $H^2$ has been ever stated and/or proved.

Let $k$ be a perfect field and $k^s$ its fixed separable closure.
Let $X^s$ be a *variety with additional structure* over $k^s$
(I don't want to specify what I mean by additional structure).
By a $k$-model of $X^s$ I mean a variety with additional structure $X$ over $k$ together with a $k^s$-isomorphism
$$ X\times_k k^s\overset{\sim}{\to} X^s.$$

> **Metatheorem.**
>   Let $k$ be a perfect field and $k^s$ its fixed separable closure.
>   Let $X^s$ be a variety with additional structure over $k^s$.
>   Write $A^s=\mathrm{Aut}(X^s)$, and assume that $A^s$ "is" an algebraic group over $k^s$.
>   Assume that for any $\sigma\in\mathrm{Gal}(k^s/k)$ there exists a $k^s$-isomorphism
>   $$\lambda_\sigma\colon \sigma X^s\to X^s,$$
>   where $\sigma X^s$ is the variety obtained from $X^s$ by transport of structure.
>   Assume also that $X^s$ admits a $k_1$-model over a finite Galois extension $k_1/k$ contained in $k^s$.
>   Then these data define a $k$-kernel
>   $$\kappa\colon\mathrm{Gal}(k^s/k)\to \mathrm{Out}(A^s)$$
>   and a cohomology class $\eta\in H^2(k,A^s,\kappa)$.
>   If $\eta$ is not neutral, then $X^s$ has no $k$-model.
>   If $\eta$ is neutral and the variety $X^s$ is quasi-projective,
>   then $X^s$ admits a $k$-model $X$. Moreover, set $A=\mathrm{Aut}(X)$,
>   then there is a canonical bijection between $H^1(k,A)$ and the set of isomorphism classes of $k$-models of $X^s$.

Example of application of the metatheorem: If $k=\mathbb{R}$, $k^s=\mathbb{C}$, $A^s$ is a finite *abelian* group of *odd* order, then $H^2(\mathbb{R},A)=1$ and  $H^1(\mathbb{R},A)=1$ (because $\mathrm{Gal}(\mathbb{C}/\mathbb{R})$ is of order 2), hence $X^s$ has a unique model over $\mathbb{R}$.

I would be also glad to have references where this metatheorem was proved in special cases.

I know that it was proved in the case when $X^s$ is a principal homogeneous space of $G^s$ dominating $Y^s$, where $Y$ is a given homogeneous space (not necessarily principal) of an algebraic group $G$ defined over $k$,  see
Springer, Nonabelian $H^2$ in Galois cohomology. In: Algebraic
Groups and Discontinuous Subgroups (Proc. Sympos. Pure Math., Boulder,
Colo., 1965), pages 164--182. Amer. Math. Soc., Providence, R.I., 1966.
Borovoi, Abelianization of the second nonabelian Galois cohomology,
Duke Math. J. 72(1), 217--239, 1993.
[Flicker, Scheiderer, Sujatha, Grothendieck's theorem on nonabelian
$H^2$ and local-global principles. J. Amer. Math. Soc. 11(3), 731--750,
1998](http://www.ams.org/journals/jams/1998-11-03/S0894-0347-98-00271-9/S0894-0347-98-00271-9.pdf).

Comment: Most of the content of the metatheorem is covered in section 12 of http://www.mathcs.emory.edu/~brussel/Papers/galoisdescent.pdf. In these terms the H^2 obstruction is the canonical obstruction to the existence of an equivariant object in a groupoid acted upon by a group.

Comment: @YonatanHarpaz: Dear Yonatan,  Could you please elaborate? Could you please kindly post an answer? The link that you give does not mention $H^2$ at all, and I don't understand what group, groupoid, and action you mean....

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Let me elaborate more on the remark above. Let $k$ be a perfect field. Let $\mathrm{Field}_k$ denote the category of finite extensions of $k$, i.e., the objects of $\mathrm{Field}_k$ are fields $k'$ equipped with an embedding $k \to k'$ such that $k'$ is finite dimensional over $k$. The morphisms are the maps of fields $k' \to k''$ which respect the embedding (here we do not think of all the $k'$ as subfield of a fixed seperable closure). Suppose we have a functor $F:\mathrm{Field}_k \to \mathrm{Grpd}$ to the category of small groupoids. For example, $F$ may be the functor which sends $k'$ to the groupoid whose objects are varieties with a certain structure defined over $k'$ and whose morphisms are structure preserving $k'$-isomorphisms between them. For $k'$ in $\mathrm{Fields}_k$ the inclusion $\iota:k \to k'$ can be considered as a morphism in $\mathrm{Fields}_k$, and we consequently have an associated functor $F(\iota):F(k) \to F(k')$ which we can call the base change functor. If $k'$ is also a Galois extension of $k$ with (finite) Galois group $G$, then the automorphism group of $k'$ in the category $\mathrm{Fields}_k$ is exactly $G$. In particular, $G$ now acts on the groupoid $F(k')$ (via functors). Given an object $X \in F(k')$ let us denote by $X^{\sigma}$ the image of $X$ under the action of $\sigma \in G$ on $F(k')$. Now whenever we have a group $G$ acting on a groupoid $Z$, we have an associated notion of a **$G$-equivariant object** of $Z$. This is an object $X \in Z$ equipped with a **compatible** collection of (iso)morphisms $f_{\sigma}: X \to X^{\sigma}$. We may also call this a **twisted** action of $G$ on $X$. Let us denote by $Z^{hG}$ the groupoid of $G$-equivariant objects in $Z$ (where the notation echoes the fact that we think of $G$-equivariant objects as **homotopy fixed points**). Now the mere fact that $F$ is a functor implies that if $X$ is an object of $F(k)$ then the object $F(\iota)(X) \in F(k')$ carries a natural twisted action of $G$. We hence obtain a functor
$$ T_{k'/k}:F(k) \to F(k')^{hG} .$$
We can now say that $F$ satisfies **Galois descent** if $T_{k'/k}$ is an equivalence of groupoids for every finite Galois extension $k'/k$.

Now the $H^2$ and $H^1$ business is something that has only to do with computing groupoids of equivariant objects, and has nothing to do with, say, algebraic varieties. Let $Z$ be a groupoid equipped with an action of a group $G$. Let $\pi_0(Z)$ denote the set of isomorphism classes of $Z$, so that we have an induced action of $G$ on $\pi_0(Z)$. If $x \in \pi_0(Z)$ is an isomorphism class fixed by $G$, then we have an induced action of $G$ on the **connected component** $Z_x \subseteq Z$ corresponding to $x$. Let $X \in Z_x$ be any object and let $A = Aut(X)$ be its automorphism group. Since $Z_x$ is a connected groupoid, the group of connected components of self-homotopy equivalences of $Z_x$ is naturally isomorphic to $Out(A)$. We hence obtain a natural map $G \to Out(A)$, i.e., a pseudo-action of $G$ on $A$. Classical obstruction theory now associates to $X$ an obstruction element $o_X \in H^2(G,A)$, which is neutral if and only if $X$ admits a $G$-equivariant structure (i.e., a twisted action of $G$). The object $o_X$ is the one associated with a certain group extension
$$ 1 \to A \to G_X \to G \to 1 $$
where $G_X$ is the group whose elements are pairs $(f,\sigma)$ where $\sigma$ is an element of $G$ and $f:X \to X^{\sigma}$ is a morphism (composition of elements is defined in a natural way). If the obstruction element $o_X$ is neutral then we can choose a section $G \to G_X$. Each such section determines a twisted action of $G$ on $X$. Furthermore, two such twisted actions result in isomorphic $G$-equivariant objects if and only if the two sections are conjugate by an element of $A$. This data is now classified by the cohomology group $H^1(G,A)$, and we obtain a bijection between $H^1(G,A)$ and the set of isomorphism classes of $G$-equivariant objects in the component $Z_x$. This is the way to compute groupoids of $G$-equivariant objects.

**Edit**:

If $Z,W$ are two groupoids then the functor category ${\rm Fun}(Z,W)$ is a groupoid as well. Two functors $f,g: Z \to W$ are *homotopic* if they are isomorphic in ${\rm Fun}(Z,W)$, and a functor $f: Z \to W$ is a *homotopy equivalence* if it has an inverse up to homotopy. For a groupoid $Z$ we have the full subgroupoid ${\rm Equiv}(Z,Z) \subseteq {\rm Fun}(Z,Z)$ spanned by the homotopy equivalences. Then $\pi_0{\rm Equiv}(Z,Z)$ (i.e., the set of isomorphism classes of the groupoid ${\rm Equiv}(Z,Z)$) is naturally a group by composition. This is the "group of connected components of self homotopy equivalences" alluded to in the answer.

Comment: I'm sure there's a neat homotopical formalization of the last paragraph but i'm struggling to find it. Here's where i'm at: Assume $Z_x= BA$ then a $G$ action on $Z_x$ is the same as a $A$ gerbe over $BG$ so we get a fiber sequence $BA \to BG \to BAut(BA)$ coming from the action of $G$ on $Z_x$ (and the choice of base point $x$). The long exact sequence in homotopy groups looks like: $0 \to Z(A) \to A \to G \to Out(A) \to *$. Here i'm basically stuck... Do you have a suggestion or perhaps a reference for this?

Comment: More generally if $F, H$ are (say connected $\infty$-)stacks on some sites, I'm trying to understand how one in practice calculates hom sets in the homotopy category of stacks $Hom_{Ho(Stacks)}(F,H)$. If everything's simply connected then one can use a Postnikov filtration to get an honest spectral sequence and one can apply standard homological algebra. However even in the nontrivial 1-truncated case I have no idea what to do. I think in this example the site is the slice category over $BG$ and $F= *, H=B\pi_1(Z_x)$.

Comment: @SaalHardali, the data of an action of $G$ on $BA$ is essentially equivalent to the data of a fibration $E \to BG$ into groupoids (which we can call a gerbe), equipped with an identification of the fiber over the base point $x \in BG$ with $BA$. The long exact sequence in homotopy groups then looks like $1 \to A \to \pi_1(E) \to G \to 1$, and there is a corresponding class in $H^2(G,A)$ which is neutral if and only the gerbe has a section. However, there doesn't seem to be any natural map which goes directly from $BA$ to $BG$, and so I'm not sure what you meant in your comment.

Comment: About the second comment, I suppose the case in question corresponds to $F=BG, H = E$, in the slice category over $BG$. In general, calculating mapping spaces in the presence of non-trivial fundamental groups can be quite painful. If fact, even for simply connected spaces $X,Y$, if you want to understand the homotopy groups of a component of $Map(X,Y)$ which is not the component of null homotopic maps then the relevant differentials in the Bousfield Kan spectral sequence will not be linear, and so the problem will not reduce to homological algebra.

Comment: Indeed I messed up and I meant to write the fiber sequence: $E \to BG \to BAut(BA)$ which gives the exact sequence $1 \to Z(A) \to \pi_1(E) \to G \to Out(A) \to 1$. Which is weirdly different than the one you wrote down although they come from the same fibration. What gives? Another thing is I didn't quite understand how one calculates the space of sections when the obstruction in $H^2(G,A)$ vanishes... Or what is this cohomology when $A$ is non-abelian...

Comment: Finally, do you have a reference for computations of this nature with the bousfield kan spectral sequence?

Comment: $E$ is not the homotopy fiber of the map $BG \to BAut(BA)$, but rather the homotopy fiber product $G \times_{BAut(BA)} BAut_*(BA)$, where $Aut_*(BA) \cong Aut(A)$ is the space of pointed automorphisms of $BA$. We hence obtain a long exact sequence $1 \to Z(A) \to \pi_1(E) \to G \times Aut(A) \to Out(A) \to 1$, which seems to be consistent with the long exact sequence $1 \to A \to \pi_1(E) \to G \to 1$.

Comment: Isn't $BA$ the fiber of $BAut_*(BA) \to BAut(BA)$? The fiber should stay the same under pullback...

Comment: and indeed the fiber of $E \to BG$ is $BA$. That's what we want $E$ to be: the family of $BA$'s over $BG$ corresponding to the action of $G$ on $BA$.

Comment: Aha! I see I messed up again sorry. This is getting too lengthy for the comment section so I just now asked a question about these issues which I think you may be able to help me with. Thanks anyway! https://mathoverflow.net/questions/280630/homotopy-theoretic-description-of-homotopy-fixed-points-and-obstructions-for-a

Comment: @YonatanHarpaz: You write: "Since $Z_x$ is a connected groupoid,  the group of connected components of self-homotopy equivalences of $Z_x$ is naturally isomorphic to $Out(A)$." What do you mean by connected components of self-homotopy equivalences? You do not define homotopy equivalences in your answer!

Comment: @MikhailBorovoi: ok, I added an edit at the end of the answer with the relevant definitions.

Comment: Thank you! Does an element of $G$ define a self homotopy equivalence, or only a connected component of the groupoid of self homotopy equivalences?

Comment: @MikhailBorovoi: An element $g\in G$ defines an actual self homotopy equivalence $T_g: Z \to Z$, not just a component. However, when considering actions of groups on groupoids it is often better not to require that $T_gT_h$ is actually equal to $T_{gh}$, but instead to prescribe homotopies of the form $H_{g,h}: T_gT_h \stackrel{\sim}{\to} T_{gh}$ (i.e., isomorphisms in $\mathrm{Equiv}(Z,Z)$) for every $g,h \in G$ which satisfy the cocycle condition $H_{gh,k} \circ H_{g,h}T_k  = H_{g,hk} \circ T_gH_{h,k}$ (as isomorphisms from $T_gT_hT_k$ to $T_{ghk}$) for every $g,h,k \in G$.